# how to enumerate theorems using letters?

Tags: numbering, theorems

how to enumerate theorems using letters?

Comment: There are some packages supporting theorems, for instance `theorem`, `amsthm` and `ntheorem`. It would be good if you mention which package do you use. Also the document class might be of importance regarding the counter presentation.

Answer (score 27):

You could redefine the presentation of the theorem counter. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\renewcommand*{\thetheorem}{\Alph{theorem}}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  Text
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Alph numbering]

If your counter has the name `theorem`, the corresponding output command has the name `\thetheorem`. The command `\Alph` takes a counter as argument and returns the value converted into the corresponding capital letter. `\alph` would return lowercase letters instead.

Comment: I tried to do the same thing for amsthm, but it did not work yet.  Where do I have to put the \Alph{}?

Comment: works wonderfully, many thanks !

Comment: How to merge letter and number, to get something like "Theorem S1.1", "Theorem S1.2" and so on?