# Theorem Ambient

Tags: numbering, theorems

it is possible to switch the list of theorems between letters and numbers?

Comment: How do you create the list of theorems? Which package do you use? Could you please show a small code example? A bit more information would make helping easier. Is this a different issue than in your other question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-to-enumerate-theorems-using-letters ?

Comment: I don't really understand your question title. Could you change it to something more descriptive? (This will likely help get you answers, too.)

Comment: Please register on this site otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

There's an option to do this with the ntheorem package. I can't remeber the specific code, but the documentation includes an example of doing that.

If you don't want to use ntheorem, then here's what you should do: Suppose the (latex) count associated with your theorem is `theorem` (if you use amsthm, I'm pretty sure this will just be the name of your theorem environment, ie the `<text>` in `\begin{<text>}`). Then after defining said theorem environment (but before `\begin{document}`) insert the following:
`\renewcommand\thetheorem{\Alph{theorem}}`
for capital letters or 
`\renewcommand\thetheorem{\alph{theorem}}`
for lowercase.