# How do I change the behaviour of enumerate inside certain theorem environments

Tags: enumerate, newtheorem

I would like to change the behaviour of enumerate inside certain theorem environments. In particular. I would like enumerate to number using the letters "a." "b." "c." etc rather than "1." "2." "3." etc in my "exercise" environment, but otherwise to behave normally, including in other theorem environments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[section]

\begin{exercise}
\begin{enumerate}
   \item Question 1
   \item Question 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this will help -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1853/197451

Comment: For future posts: Please provide a full example document in such a case, i.e. include also the `\documentclass{article}` etc into your code example, such that it will be compiled by LaTeX. This simplifies the answering

Comment: @MaximilianKeßler thanks -- will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use the `enumitem` package, which enables you to easily change the default style of your `enumerate` environments.

Combining this approach with the $\LaTeX$ hook system (`texdoc hooks`), we can modify the default labelling style within each `exercise` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[section]

\AddToHook{ env/exercise/begin } { \setlist [enumerate] { label=\alph*. } }

\begin{document}

Start a list:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item foo
\end{enumerate}

List inside environment:
\begin{exercise}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Question 1
    \item Question 2
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}

List after environment:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item foo
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Note also that the change of the label is contained inside the `exercise` environment, since `\begin{...}` also starts grouping, and we used the `begin` hook, which inserts our code *after* entering the `exercise` environment, but before processing its contents.
Thus, we do not need to restore the behavior manually after the end of the `exercise`, as you observe in the example document.

Comment: +1 for a well formulated answer. If the user is using an old LaTeX without the hooks, then one can do a similar thing via the `etoolbox` package.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly!