# Printing counter options

Tags: theorems, counters

I want to use `\Alph{mycounter}` to have my theorems labelled by capital roman letters and a short search led me to conclude that all I need to write is

```
\newcounter{mycounter}
\Alph{mycounter}
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{mainthm}[mycounter]{Theorem}
```

Upon compilation of

```
\begin{mainthm}
   Something.
\end{mainthm}

\begin{mainthm}
   Something else.
\end{mainthm}
```

I get "Theorem 1. Something." and "Theorem 2. Something else.". Do I need to fix something in my syntax? I also tried removing some possibly conflicting packages like `amsthm` and `cleveref`, to no avail.

Comment: BTW: You can generally increase your chances of a qualified answer by showing not just snippets of code, but a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the numbering of \part, \chapter, \section, ... to alphabetical, Roman numbers, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3177/how-to-change-the-numbering-of-part-chapter-section-to-alphabetical-r) or [how to enumerate theorems using letters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/277964)

Comment: @cabohah Thanks, the answer in second link works! And I'll be more careful next time with the MWE. Do I need to add the solution to my question?

Comment: @LorenzoRiva no, you don't. Your question will be closed as duplicate, making it yet another link to the question which helped you, you don't have to do anything else here. Glad you found a solution!